# Custom execution strategy for connection resiliency with PostgreSql and EntityFramework Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I work on an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application that uses PostgreSql as Database.

Entity Framework Core 1.1 has an connection resiliency feature that seems nice.

All documentation I have found is for Microsoft SQL Server, but I use PostgreSql and I've tried to figure out how can I create my own custom execution strategy.
But (again) I didn't find any documentation.

Did you have any idea how to do that?

I need resiliency because I dockerise my service, and often, my application is ready before the database. So the app doesn't find the database and crashes...